# Jetpack Compose preview stopped working in Arctic Fox with Patch 1

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-arctic-fox, android-jetpack-compose-preview

With the first patch for AS Arctic Fox Jetpack Compose previews stopped working.

I'm getting this error for **all** previews - even older ones, which worked fine a while back:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: [some hex value]
```

Are here any quick fixes for this? Clearing caches and the usual stuff did not work.

**EDIT:** 
Looks like the problem is not always present. Some preview started working, while other are still failing.

**EDIT 2:** 
This is happening in dynamic feature modules, when there's a need for resources from the main module or `painterResource()` is being used (even is resource from the same module is to be displayed).

Comment: I have similar problem - in my case compose has problem with fetching `dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.some_value)` in preview + I'm using preview 2

Comment: Is this the issue in the main module? Any module? Dynamic feature module?

Comment: Yes I have this problem only in dynamic feature

Comment: I have the same issue.                 Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.flower4)
                ) is not working

Comment: I have same issue with color resources.(dynamic module refers app module resource)

Comment: I have this issue in non-dynamic module, but when the string resource is in another module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This got fixed in AS Bumblebee, patch 2.

Edit (copied from comments): It then got broken again in `Electric Eel | 2022.1.1` and fixed again in `Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Beta 4`.

Edit 2 (copied from comments - Feb 2024): It apparently got broken again in Giraffe and Hedgehog.

Comment: maybe but it is present in Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1
or very similar issue where you need to refresh manually preview again after each change for this error to dissapear.

Comment: Fixed in Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Beta 4

Comment: Well, seems to be broken again on Giraffe and Hedgehog...

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here with dynamic-modules project.
Inspired by above answer, I've made another **temporary workaround** while waiting for Compose team to fix this.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource as originalStringResource

@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun stringResourceSafe(@StringRes id: Int): String =
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
        try {
            resources.getString(id)
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            "missing res."
        }
    } else {
        originalStringResource(id)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it starts working after run the application on a simulator (2022.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got to solve the issue by using

```
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
```

instead of

```
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.02.02"))
```

Android Studio HedgeHog 2023.1.1 Patch 2

Answer (score -1):

As a temporary hack workaround I did this to get past the error and preview the UI elements.

```kotlin
//import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource

fun stringResource(id: Int): String {
    when (id) {
        R.string.res_id -> return "Foo"
        ...
    }
    return "missing res_id"
}
```