# Compose @Preview is not working for composable in dynamic feature module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

For composables in dynamic feature module of my app, `@Preview` annotation does not display the preview in Android stuido.
Such error is displayed:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F080255.
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1153)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1129)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1133)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getResourceValue(Resources_Delegate.java:921)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:892)
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1428)
at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource(PainterResources.android.kt:60)
at de.test.pay.ui.settings.freeze.ComposableSingletons$MyScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MyScreen.kt:54)
at de.test.pay.ui.settings.freeze.ComposableSingletons$MyScreenKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MyScreen.kt:52)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.material.IconButtonKt.IconButton(IconButton.kt:80)
at de.test.pay.ui.settings.freeze.ComposableSingletons$MyScreenKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MyScreen.kt:52)
at de.test.pay.ui.settings.freeze.ComposableSingletons$MyScreenKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(MyScreen.kt:51)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.material.AppBarKt$TopAppBar$1.invoke(AppBar.kt:98)
at androidx.compose.material.AppBarKt$TopAppBar$1.invoke(AppBar.kt:93)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.material.AppBarKt$AppBar$1.invoke(AppBar.kt:562)
at androidx.compose.material.AppBarKt$AppBar$1.invoke(AppBar.kt:510)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$6.invoke(Surface.kt:267)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$6.invoke(Surface.kt:254)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:251)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:110)
at androidx.compose.material.AppBarKt.AppBar-celAv9A(AppBar.kt:504)
at androidx.compose.material.AppBarKt.TopAppBar-xWeB9-s(AppBar.kt:86)
at de.test.pay.ui.settings.freeze.MyScreenKt.Toolbar(MyScreen.kt:47)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:149)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:188)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:571)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:569)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:608)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:513)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:512)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:508)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:121)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:561)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:150)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3332)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2577)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2566)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2517)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:477)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:727)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:814)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Composable:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Toolbar() {
   TopAppBar(
       title = { Text(text = "test") },
       backgroundColor = Color.White,
       elevation = 0.dp,
       navigationIcon = {
           IconButton(onClick = { }) {
               Icon(
                   painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.black_back_icon),
                   contentDescription = null
               )
           }
       }
   )
}
```

**Android Studio version:** Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

**Compose version:**  1.0.5

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845898/jetpack-compose-preview-stopped-working-in-arctic-fox-with-patch-1

Comment: Seems like it was fixed in Android Studio Bumblebee Canary 8 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195021097

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Canary 7. Fixed it by adding the following dependencies directly into Dynamic Feature Module:

```
implementation platform(androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00)
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
debugImplementation  "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
```

In my case, DFM uses all dependencies from the app module via `api` configuration, but it didn't work with Compose Preview dependencies in this way.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Using api in base module instead of implementation doesn't work, and it seems that it is not related to Android Studio version (I am using stable version - Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2). In my case i didn't need the 3rd line, it worked without implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview".